# Syntax error: Operator expected in prolog code

Tags: prolog

I'm new to prolog .. i tried this code but got error and don't know why ?!

```
de(F,L,R):-
R=[F|L].
```

is that because rule must have a recursion ?
the error is

```
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
```

Comment: No, a rule does not need recursion. If I test this locally, I do not get an error anyway.

Comment: i tested it as de[a,[a,1,2,3],Z].

Comment: well that is indeed a syntax error, you need to use parenthesis when calling a predicate, so `de(a, [a,3,4,5,2], Z)`.

Comment: ohhh, thanks i missed it really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59619223/syntax-error-operator-expected-in-prolog-code?noredirect=1#comment105401872_59619223), you specify what you did wrong:

> i tested it as `de[a,[a,1,2,3],Z].`

When you call a predicate, you use parenthesis (`(…)`), square brackets (`[…]`) are used to construct lists. You thus should call the predicate with parenthesis:

```
?- def(a,[a,1,2,3],Z).
Z = [a, a, 1, 2, 3].
```